# Android app and static storage between activities

Tags: android, android-activity, static, singleton, storage

i have an Android application in which i use a class to store static data among activities, something like:

```
class Global
{
      private static boolean mInitialized = false;
  private static String  mData        = null;

  public static void init()
  {
    mData        = "something";
    mInitialized = true;
  }

      public static boolean isInitialized()
      {
            return mInitialized;
      }

  public static String getData()
  {
    return mData;
  }
}
```

So in the main activity onCreate i do:

```
if( Global.isInitialized() == false )
    Global.init();
```

And then starts other activities, the action flow is:

MainActivity -> ActionActivity -> PluginActivity

Where Main is where i init the Global class, and Action & Plugin is where i use the getData() method of that class.

Now in some cases, i get really strange behaviour ... if something unepected happens in PluginActivity ( NullPointerException for instance ), the activity crashes and the application goes back to the ActionActivity which launched it, but, at this point, during the onCreate of the ActionActivity ( where the Global class is supposed to be initialized ) i get an exception because the getData() returns null ( and isInitialized() is false ) as the Global class was never initialized by the MainActivity.

So, can an object with static members like my Global class be deallocated/cleared/whatever if something like an unexpected exception occurs ?

Comment: Why don't you try to make this class as singleton....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, activities should be independent of each other. You should not depend on them being launched in any particular order, or at all.

Instead, if you need to share global state data between activities, i.e. not just parameter passing in intent extras or results via `onActivityResult()`, subclass `Application`, put the init code in its `onCreate()` and access it from activities using `getApplication()`. Also remember to declare the application class in your manifest. The system takes care that the application object is there when any of your activities are running.

Comment: and the application object is persistent or it could be reinitialized/reallocaed if needed ? I have to be sure that my data is initialized only once ...

Comment: There's at most just one instance of the application object at any time. It's not persisted but created when your app is starting. If you need persistence, use a database, `SharedPreferences`, files or something like that.

Comment: i meant persistance during the application lifecycle, so yes, it is persistent :)

Answer (score 0):

In Android, whenever application crashes the static variable will be discarded. This is the reason why you are getting `NullPointerException`. Instead of making the object static create a `Parcelable` or `Serializable`  class and get and set the fields and then pass that object with the intent. In another activity you can get that `Parcelable` or `Serializable` class and you can use its property.

Comment: I don't need a serializable object, i do not have to read every time from filesystem storage or something like that, i just need it to be persistent over app lifecycle.

Comment: In Application class if you will set your object and if your application will be crashed then you will loose your object. So better you check the value of the object in the method `getData()` and if the object is null create a instance of the class so the object will be re Initialized.

Comment: If the whole app crashes, it's ok for me to loose the object :)

Comment: Then better you use the Application class as @laalto has suggest you.